# How to add syncing file icons to files in a specific folder?

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, directory

I'm creating a dropbox like program that syncs a file contents with a server. I need to add the mini sycing icons that subversion and Dropbox add to the file as I'm syncing it. I have no idea how to do that. I assume its messing with the thumbs.db file or something. (Syncing, Not Synced, Synced, not syncable - 4 diffrent icons)

I'm using VB.net with the Latest Windows Framework (4 or less).

Comment: They are icon overlays. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496582/net-how-do-i-create-file-icon-overlays